# How to create a simple full screen box in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to reword this:

I would like to create a white background header with no hover (currently it is white), a full-width yellow box underneath which does not span the height of the screen, possibly expands when I add to it? A small white text box inside, and an image to the right-hand side of this.

So far I have:

```
    <html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />


</head>
<body>
        <div class="header">

                <a class="logo" target="_blank"><img src=".\images\logo.png" border="0" alt="logo" width="90"></a>
                <div class="header-left">
                  <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                  <a href="wall.html">Wall</a>
                  <a href="shop.html">Shop</a>
                  <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                  <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
            <div class="header-right">
                  <a class="active" href="http://instagram.com/woolybox" target="_blank"><img src=".\images\instagram.png" border="0" alt="instagram"img width="20" height="20"></a>
                  <a href="http://twitter.com/wooly_box" target="_blank"><img src=".\images\twitter.png" border="0" alt="twitter" img width="20" height="20"></a>

                </div>
                </div>
    <table><tr><td>


    Hello
        </td></tr></table>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body { 
  height: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%; 

  border-width: 0; 
  border-style: solid;
  border: #fff;
}

  table { 
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%; 
    background-color: #f4d442;
  }

td { 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: left;}

.header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }


  .header a {
    float: left;
    color: grey;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding-top: 16px;
    padding: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 18px; 
    line-height: 25px;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }


  .header a.logo {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }


  .header a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: black;
  }


  .header a.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #f4d442;
  }


  .header-right {
    float: right;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .header a {
      float: none;
      background-color: #fff;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

  .header-right {
      float: none;
    }
  }
```

My outcome ends up as a thin yellow box like so:

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEE3P.jpg)

I am following this mockup I have made using Adobe XD and MDL components. Again, I am extremely out of practice and trying to understand a lot of new things.

[MockUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDOOB.jpg)

Comment: Please add relevant code of the problem

Comment: There isn’t enough code posted. The div you’re trying to add is clearly inside of a container that’s bounding it, so the first thing to do is break that div or remove its margins/padding/width values.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this hasn't helped as if I remove any other padding I ruin the entire thing. As I said, Ive been out the game for at least 10 years, I'm still very much a novice so I'm not sure where to look :(

Comment: What are you using to make the code? An IDE like PHPStorm/ WebStorm or maybe even an text editor like vscode would have shown some errors in your CSS

Comment: I am using VS Code, no errors showing, I know this is very basic but I have limited knowledge of this stuff from a building point of view, this is the first site I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?  Set the body height and whatnot to 100%.  Then play with the inner height relative %s.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; border-width: 5; border-style: solid; }
table { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
td { height: 100%; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table><tr><td>
Hello
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot....

```
.boxed {
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
box-align: center;
background-color:  #f4d442;
padding: 25px;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: This has worked well size-wise, still having some issues with my left side. My header appears to be transparent and the box is showing under it, but changing the background to white doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your `padding` and `margin` are adding extra space around your yellow `div`. If you right click on your yellow `div` in the web page and select "Inspect", you'll be able to see the effects of those styles.

Next, if you want the yellow `div` to be full-screen, you'll need it to take up 100% of its parent container. The parent container must have a defined `height`, and the grandparent container must have a defined `height`, etc. all the way up to the highest level: the `html` tag. In the code snippet below, I've set the yellow `div`'s parent containers' `height` to make the yellow `div` full-scren.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.boxed {
  background-color: #f4d442;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="boxed">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="boxed">Lorem Epsum</div>
```

.boxed {width: 100%;box-align: center;background-color: #f4d442;padding: 25px;margin: 0;}